# What are all the key/values in a Parse query result for?

Tags: json, parse-platform

When I make a query using Parse, I get a result back that includes an array of objects, where each object includes these items:

```
_serverData
_opSetQueue
attributes
_hashedJSON
_escapedAttributes
cid
changed
_silent
_pending
_hasData
_previousAttributes
id
createdAt
updatedAt
```

I can't find any documentation about what all of these are for and how I would use them. Of course, some are self-explanatory (i.e. `createdAt`) but some are much more vague (i.e. `silent`)

What are these items for?